# JSQMessageViewController customize send button

Tags: ios, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm building an messaging app, I use JSQMessageViewController to render messages and it's awesome.
Now I have a little problem trying to customize the send button:

Basically I want to replace left and right BarButtonItem to customized button with images.
After some hours of reading and searching, I got this far now:

[button without text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIcGm.png)

[button with text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYiwR.png)

As shown in the pictures, the voice button which is replacing the original send button is disabled if there is no text in the textField, this behavior is not what I want. How do I disable this behavior and make the button available all the time?

And this is how I customize the send button:

```
  UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  [rightButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"AudioButton@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  self.inputToolbar.contentView.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want button available all the time,
Find This method in  "JSQMessagesInputToolbar.h" And Comment These lines in **OLD Code**

```
- (void)toggleSendButtonEnabled
{
BOOL hasText = [self.contentView.textView hasText];

//    if (self.sendButtonOnRight) {
//        self.contentView.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = hasText;
//    }

//    else {
//        self.contentView.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = hasText;
//    }

}
```

**in New JSQ Code**

```
- (void)updateSendButtonEnabledState
{
 if (!self.enablesSendButtonAutomatically) {
    return;
}

BOOL enabled = [self.contentView.textView hasText];
//    switch (self.sendButtonLocation) {
//        case JSQMessagesInputSendButtonLocationRight:
//            self.contentView.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = enabled;
//            break;
//        case JSQMessagesInputSendButtonLocationLeft:
//            self.contentView.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = enabled;
//            break;
//        default:
//            break;
//    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks varinder, it works. But, IMHO, they should make this configurable.

Answer (score 0):

this will work if you are replacing your custom button in `rightBarButtonItem`

add this in viewDidAppear

```
[self.inputToolbar.contentView.rightBarButtonItem setEnabled:YES];
```

and override textview delegate

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView;
```